# HAproxy ACL dynamically match part of path to a header

Tags: haproxy

Using HAproxy 1.8 I am trying to create an ACL which should dynamically match a given part of the url/path to a given header.

The portal in front of the HAproxy adds header for auth users:

`X-roles MQ-QUEUE(QUEUE=test.queue,QUEUE=foobar.queue)`

The accessed URL looks like:
https://portal/mqsrv/some/custom/path/with/queue/test.queue/in/path

my configuration so far:

```
frontend main
    ...
    acl src_portal src 192.168.5.0/24
    acl url_mqsrv path_beg -i /mqsrv
    # working static approach
    acl perm_mq req.fhdr(X-roles) -m str MQ-QUEUE(QUEUE=test.queue) if { path -m /test.queue/ }
    # how to achieve this dynamically?
    # 
    ...
    use_backend backend_mqsrv if src_portal url_mqsrv perm_mq
```

I tried to get the part of the path via regex into a variable like:

`http-request set-var(txn.requested_queue) path,reg(queue\/(\K.*)\/ \1)`

That does not work, because 'reg' is an unknown converter. Other attempts were using the regex to get the queue from the path for a match against the role header but I can not find a working way how to extract the queue part from a request path to use it for the role-header match. Another idea would be to use a lua script but that would not be as performant as an acl-match I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to do that without using a lua script, so I solved it this way:

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    ...
    # load loa script to check MQ-QUEUE() role
    lua-load /etc/haproxy/check-roles.lua

frontend main
    bind hap-rip:80
    capture request header   X-roles len 50
    http-request set-var(txn.roles) req.fhdr(X-roles)
    http-request set-var(txn.request_urlpath) path
    acl src_portal  src      192.168.5.0/24
    acl url_mqsrv  path_beg -i /mqsrv
    # if acl matches, use backend_mqsrv
    use_backend backend_mqsrv   if src_portal url_mqsrv { lua.queue_allowed(txn.roles,txn.request_urlpath) -m bool true }
    # if no acl matches the request, use default backend which serves a 403 forbidden response
    default_backend backend_no-match

backend backend_mqsrv
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    balance     leastconn
    acl src_portal  src      192.168.5.0/24
    http-request    deny     unless src_portal
    # remove /mqsrv/ from request url
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /mqsrv/(.*) \1\ /\2
    # echo -n "username:password" | base64
    reqadd Authorization:\ Basic\ *********************=
    server mqsrv mqsrv.domain.local:443 ssl check-ssl check verify none

backend backend_no-match
    # tcp-request content reject
    mode http
    http-request deny deny_status 403
```

/etc/haproxy/check-roles.lua:

```
-- example url https://portal/mqsrv/some/custom/path/with/queue/test.queue/in/path
-- example role header from portal: X-roles: MQ-QUEUE(QUEUE=ABC,QUEUE=test.queue,QUEUE=XYZ)

-- notes on haproxy lua logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879666/haproxy-lua-logging

-- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/lua/lua+split+string+by+delimiter
function Split(s, delimiter)
    result = {};
    for match in (s..delimiter):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
        table.insert(result, match);
    end
    return result;
end

-- function to check if requested queue (from url path) is contained in roles-header (injected from portal)
-- https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/
core.register_fetches("queue_allowed", function(txn, var1, var2)
    -- get role and path values from request
    local roles_authorized = txn:get_var(var1)
    core.log(core.info, "roles header: " .. roles_authorized)
    -- extract requested queue from url/path
    local request_urlpath = txn:get_var(var2)
    -- local requested_queue = Split(request_urlpath,"/")[10] -- get requested queue by position
    local requested_queue = request_urlpath:match("queue%/(.*)%/") -- get requested queue by matching string after 'queue/'
    core.log(core.info, "requested_queue: " .. requested_queue)
    -- extract QUEUES from MQ-QUEUE() header
    queues = Split(Split(roles_authorized,'%(')[2],'%)')[1]
    core.log(core.info, "queues: " .. queues)
    -- loop through comma seperated queues to check if requested queue is found
    for _,item in pairs(Split(queues,',')) do
        queue = Split(item,'=')[2]
        core.log(core.info, "authorized queue: " .. queue)
        if queue == requested_queue then
            core.log(core.info, "requested queue " .. requested_queue .. " matched with authorized queue " .. queue .. " - allowing request!")
            return true
        end
    end
end)
```